# Can existing entities be related to other newly added entity to ObjectContext by adding them in its collection navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

Will the foreign key in the first set of entities be updated with the IDENTITY of newly added entity ? Is this possible ?

I have a Users table and Agencies table.

Users have a AgencyId foreign key that can be null.

So in my Entity Framework ObjectContext I will have an Agency entity that will have Users as navigation property of type collection of Users.

I add a new object to Agency entity and then I know I can add Users objects to that Agency entity and they will be saved to database.

But what I want is:

I want to add already existing Users to that Agency entity, so that whatever identity is generated for that new Agency in datbase, it goes into the foreign key "AgencyId" of Users table for those users which are added to this Agency.

Can this be done using entity framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can be done. Just do:

```
var agency = new Agency { ... };

foreach (var user in context.Users.Where(u => ...))
{
    agency.Users.Add(user);
}

context.Agencies.Add(agency);
context.SaveChanges();
```

All foreign keys in user entities will be set to new id of inserted agency.

Comment: Actually, I tried it before and I was getting some error, therefore I thought may be I missed something, so I asked it here. I will try it again. - Thankyou.